# How to load category image in frontend?

Tags: magento2, category, megamenu, category-image

We have created a megamenu and want to load the category image on the menu. I'm not sure how to load that.

As of now, we have just hardcoded the image.

Below is the code:

```
<?php
namespace Butterfly\Megamenu\Block;
class Categorylist extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_categoryHelper;
    protected $categoryFactory;
    protected $_catalogLayer;
    protected $_categoryRepository;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,     
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,        

        array $data = []
    ) {


        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;   
    $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,          
            $data
        );


    }

    public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }

    public function getCategoryById($categoryId) 
    {
        return $this->_categoryRepository->get($categoryId);

    }

public function  getSubcategories($categories, $parent= '') {
    $i = 0;
    $array= '<ul class="child">';
    foreach($categories->getChildrenCategories() as $category) {
        $array .= '<li>';
        $cat_image = 'https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/pirate.jpg?w=990&crop=1';
        if($i == 3 && $parent == '' && $cat_image != ""){
            $array .= '<img class="u_cat_image" src="'.$cat_image.'" />';
            $array .= '</li><li>';
        }
        $array .= '<a href="/newmagento/' .$category->getRequestPath().'">' .
                  $category->getName() . "</a>\n";
        if($category->hasChildren()) {
            $children = $this->getCategoryById($category->getId());
             $array .=  $this->getSubcategories($children, 'child');
            }
         $array .= '</li>';
         $i++;
    }
    return  $array . '</ul>';
}


}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

---

I can see the category images in DB:

[image]

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can get Category Image using this function **$category->getImageUrl()**

You can use this in your code like..

```
<?php
namespace Butterfly\Megamenu\Block;

class Categorylist extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_categoryHelper;
    protected $categoryFactory;
    protected $_catalogLayer;
    protected $_categoryRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,

        array $data = []
    ) {

        $this->_categoryHelper     = $categoryHelper;
        $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );

    }

    public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted, $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }

    public function getCategoryById($categoryId)
    {
        return $this->_categoryRepository->get($categoryId);

    }

    public function getSubcategories($categories, $parent = '')
    {
        $i     = 0;
        $array = '<ul class="child">';
        foreach ($categories->getChildrenCategories() as $category) {
            $array .= '<li>';
            $cat_image = $category->getImageUrl();
            if ($i == 3 && $parent == '' && $cat_image != "") {
                $array .= '<img class="u_cat_image" src="' . $cat_image . '" />';
                $array .= '</li><li>';
            }
            $array .= '<a href="/newmagento/' . $category->getRequestPath() . '">' .
            $category->getName() . "</a>\n";
            if ($category->hasChildren()) {
                $children = $this->getCategoryById($category->getId());
                $array .= $this->getSubcategories($children, 'child');
            }
            $array .= '</li>';
            $i++;
        }
        return $array . '</ul>';
    }

}
```

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: Thank you. I will try and let you know the status

Comment: Is this working for you then ?

Comment: I have tried the code as you suggested but its not working. I have uploaded the image in category via admin. I'm not sure what am I missing. Please help

Comment: Can you please run **php bin/magento cache:clean** and **php bin/magento cache:flush** commands ?

then please refresh your frontend with above code.

Comment: Yes I have run the cache flush and clean commands but not displaying the image

Comment: what are you getting there? Can you please add this line there **var_dump($category->getImageUrl());** there and check what you're getting there ? NULL or anything else ?

Comment: When I add the line var_dump($category->getImageUrl());, I'm getting the bool(false) error

Comment: It means that for that product ID you do not have any category image in backend.

Comment: So, First replace this **var_dump($category->getImageUrl());** with **var_dump($category->getId());** and then go to backend and open that category and check in Content tab there is any image available or not ? If not then please upload image and then save that category and then again replace **var_dump($category->getId());** this with **var_dump($category->getImageUrl());** this one and clear magento cache and refresh your page. It will work.

Comment: As you said, I have got the Id while tried with getId(); and then uploaded an image at  one of the sub category and replaced the getId(); to getImageUrl(); , and then run the commands flush, clean the cache. However, I'm not still getting the image in frontend instead I'm getting bool(false).

Comment: Can you please run this query in your database and check image name is available for your category ID or not ? **SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id` = 48**

Comment: I have run the query and got the images name for the category ID. I have attached the screenshot in question.

Comment: You're not getting image for any single category in your menu ?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue I'm having. Please help

Comment: Which Magento version you're using ?

Comment: I'm using Magento 2.3.2 Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 0):

update `getSubcategories()` function with below

```
<?php
namespace Butterfly\Megamenu\Block;
class Categorylist extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_categoryHelper;
    protected $categoryFactory;
    protected $_catalogLayer;
    protected $_categoryRepository;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,     
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,        
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;   
        $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,          
            $data
        );


    }

    public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }

    public function getCategoryById($categoryId) 
    {
        return $this->_categoryRepository->get($categoryId);

    }

    public function  getSubcategories($categories, $parent= '') {
        $i = 0;
        $array= '<ul class="child">';
        foreach($categories->getChildrenCategories() as $subcat) {
            $category = $this->getCategoryById($subcat->getId());

            $cat_image = $_category->getImageUrl();

            if($cat_image == ""){
                $array .= '<li>';
                $cat_image = 'https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/pirate.jpg?w=990&crop=1';
                $array .= '<img class="u_cat_image" src="'.$cat_image.'" />';
                $array .= '</li><li>';
            }
            $array .= '<a href="/newmagento/' .$category->getRequestPath().'">' .
                      $category->getName() . "</a>\n";
            if($category->hasChildren()) {
                $children = $this->getCategoryById($category->getId());
                 $array .=  $this->getSubcategories($children, 'child');
                }
             $array .= '</li>';
             $i++;
        }
        return  $array . '</ul>';
    }


}
```